# How to find out the element where a function was called from (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is my my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select class="option_block" size="5" multiple="1">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
            <option>Option 5</option>
       </select>

       <div class="button_block" multiple="1">

            <button class="move_button" id="MoveAllToRight">>></button>
            <button class="move_button" id="MoveToRight">></button>
            <button class="move_button" id="MoveToLeft"><</button>
            <button class="move_button" id="MoveAllToLeft"><<</button>

       </div>

    <select class="option_block" size="5"></select>

</div>

<script src="scripts/javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Adh here is my JS-script:

```
(function(){

function move(direction) {
..........
}

function moveAll(direction) {
...........
}


document.getElementById("MoveAllToRight").addEventListener("click", function () {
    moveAll('ToRight');
});

document.getElementById("MoveToRight").addEventListener("click", function () {
    move('ToRight');
});

document.getElementById("MoveToLeft").addEventListener("click", function () {
    move('ToLeft');
});

document.getElementById("MoveAllToLeft").addEventListener("click", function () {
    moveAll('ToLeft');
});


})();
```

I decided not to show contain of `move` and `moveAll` functon because it's obviously excessive information.

How can I get access to "div" that contains both elements inside `move` and `moveAll` functions ?
I have a solution with using of "ID"'s, but it's not scalable.

Comment: `document.getElementById("MoveAllToLeft").parentElement`

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` (of the `event` parameter) or `this` in the respective callback, and pass it into `move`/`moveAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("MoveAllToRight").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    moveAll(event, 'ToRight');
});
```

Inside the function `event.target` will show you the element from which the event was invoked.

Comment: You forgot to pass the `event` object to the callback.

Comment: Calling `moveAll(event, 'ToRight')`  will execute the function and not attach it as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you bind your event listeners to something else explicitly the 'this' keyword will become the element from which the event was triggered.

So you should be able to access the parent div by doing

```
this.parentElement
```

Or figure out how to walk the Dom with whatever library you are working with